# GPG usage in Python vs. Shell - memory & speed

Tags: python, encryption, gnupg

been reading and horsing around with GPG on the Debian shell / bash and in Python. Related Questions are: [Large File encryption with python-gnupg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35421076/how-to-encrypt-a-large-dataset-using-python-gnupg-without-sucking-up-all-the-mem) and [Using GPG in Python via ShellCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56568166/pipe-stream-gnupg-output-to-tarfile-in).
So I got it working both ways but experience a huge difference in encoding time needed. Using python-gnupg will take more than double the time the bash command will need.
Can anybody explain to me why this is?
At this moment my programm is not really time sensitive, but with growing file size this will most certainly become an issue in the near future...

Comment: No, we cannot without code and your testing technique. But probably it is a difference between streaming and buffering the entire message in RAM.

Comment: Hi Maarten, thanks for your answere. The file is 17GB and I encrypt it on a raspberry pi 4. This specs given, it is clear, that it is impossible to load the file into ram. That's why I mentioned "Large File encryption with python-gnupg". 
I guess the streaming approach Jens Erat suggested < with (x, "rb) as y > is somehow used in the bash command as well.